# How can I capture an Android crash stack trace from the error reporting UI without rooting my phone?

Tags: android, crash-reports

I have a crashing Android app whose error reports I'm sending to the developers, but I'd also just like to capture the stack trace myself as text.

I tried LogCat and CrashLog on the Play store to email myself the error report contents, but the former requires root access, and I haven't been able to get the latter to do anything.

Ideally I could just copy/paste the stack trace text (which I can perfectly well view and screen capture) myself, but this doesn't seem to be possible.  Are crash logs saved to the SD card somewhere?  Any other tips (I'm using Android 4.2.1)?

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.2 locked down the logs so apps can only access their own log information. Also, bear in mind that the developer may already be getting this crash log, via the Play Store Developer Console or add-on libraries like ACRA

If you are an app developer, you can use the development tools (e.g., DDMS) to view the full logs, and copy/paste the logs to send to your fellow developer.

If you are not an app developer, settle for the screenshot.

> Are crash logs saved to the SD card somewhere?

No, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Ok -- that's what I suspected.  Screenshot it is in this case :-/  Thanks very much!